# Wordpress custom SQL to fecth three posts with given meta values

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, greatest-n-per-group

I have bunch of custom post type footer elements with a meta key `footer_element_meta_alignment`. Now, I'm trying to fetch three latest posts, which `meta_values` are `1`, `2` and `3`. So, one post with each of those values.

How can I achieve this with single SQL Query?

This is my SQL Query so far:

```
"SELECT wposts.*, meta1.meta_value
FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta meta1
WHERE 1=1
AND wposts.post_type = 'footer_element'
AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
AND wposts.ID = meta1.post_id
AND meta1.meta_key = 'footer_element_meta_alignment'
AND (meta1.meta_value = 1 OR meta1.meta_value = 2 OR meta1.meta_value = 3)
ORDER BY meta1.meta_value ASC";
```

That however fetches all elements with given meta values, and not only the latest one.

**ANSWER**
Answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed (I hope).

```
 SELECT wposts.* FROM $wpdb->posts wposts WHERE
 wposts.post_type = 'footer_element'
 AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
 AND wposts.ID IN 
 (SELECT max(meta1.post_id) FROM $wpdb->postmeta meta1
 WHERE meta1.meta_value = 1 OR meta1.meta_value = 2 OR meta1.meta_value = 3
 GROUP BY meta1.meta_value)
```

Comment: That gives me an SQL error, and if I remove the `as q` it doesn't, but it won't find any posts either

Comment: @micadelli oh right, alias wasn't needed cause that ain't a subquery. And it should have been count(*)=3 not count(*)>3. I guess I should pay more attention to the code.

Comment: @micadelli and what's the result for `SELECT meta1.post_id, count(*) FROM $wpdb->postmeta meta1
 WHERE meta1.meta_value = 1 OR meta1.meta_value = 2 OR meta1.meta_value = 3
 GROUP BY meta1.post_id`?

Comment: @micadelli wait a second. I misread you. I thought it's supposed to search for a post that has all the three tags not three posts with one tag each. Gimme a moment.

Comment: still no go! that finds only the two oldest elements, one with meta value 2, and one with meta value 3.

Comment: @micadelli in that case I'd say that you don't have a post with value 1 (if you remove where clause in subquery it will return latest posts for any post). Though I probably should get someone to look at it as I'm getting confused too now.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling few hours I found a solution for this.

**SQL**

```
"SELECT *
 FROM (  SELECT p.*, m.meta_value AS meta
         FROM $wpdb->posts AS p
         LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS m
         ON p.ID = m.post_id
         WHERE m.meta_key = 'footer_element_meta_alignment'
         AND p.post_status = 'publish'
         ORDER BY m.meta_value ASC, p.post_date DESC) AS h
 GROUP BY meta";
```